# R bar plot with hour breaks from datetime

Tags: r, datetime, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a bar plot in R with breaks based on the hour of a datetime. Here's a sample of the data I'm working with:

```
    966,34,2013-12-27 06:48:20,219.0,921.423404575176661
    966,26,2013-12-23 07:19:18,147.0,1997.267748145552894
    966,18,2013-12-20 07:32:29,195.0,1569.149919735630304
    966,11,2013-12-19 12:15:19,955.0,4780.830543328801945
```

The first two columns are forms of ids which I am not interested in. The third column is the datetime object. The fourth and fifth columns are the ones I want to represent in bar plots (a plot for each column). My problem is that I cannot figure out how to calculate the average values of column 4 (and 5) based only on the hour of the day, and display that in a barplot.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tryed the `aggregate()` function? For some tasks it's helpfull to convert POSIXct to POSIXlt format.

Comment: I have had trouble in the past doing this sort of thing as well, you can try using the `as.DATE()` or using the Lubridate package to help format the date. I would suggest doing a search on SO for what your looking for I know there are many timeseries related questions for plotting in R and welcome to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
group <- list(strftime(df$datetime, format = "%H"))
```

to convert the datetime strings into a list of hours to aggregate by.

I'd then aggregate the column of values whose means you want:

```
means <- aggregate(df$values, by = group, FUN = mean)
```

I don't know whether this a particularly good method but it works for me.